# How to check for extensions functions at compile time in Typescript

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, extension-methods

I am looking for a way of failing at compile time if a developer is using an extension function without importing the implementation file

File string.d.ts

```
export {};

declare global {
    interface String {
        padZero (length: number): string;
    }
}
```

File string.extensions.ts

```
String.prototype.padZero = function (this: string, length: number): string {
   ... implementation
}
```

Anywhere in the code

```
'TEST'.padZero(10); // Fails at runtime because "import '...string.extensions.ts';" was forgotten
```

How to make sure the import is done correctly at compilation time ?

EDIT : I didn't find a way but the import is only needed once for the app so you can do it in app.module.ts for example and it's ok

Comment: declarations are good for types, but they are no guarantee for your code working. You should have tests in your code to ensure your functionality works

Comment: I'm not trying to test the implementation of padZero, I want to avoid any runtime error because someone forgot an import (if it's possible)